# TCaptureDeviceManager getting video capture devices for multiple web cams

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder, video-capture

I have an application written in C++Builder 11.1.5, where I am trying to capture live video from 2 web cams.

There is an excellent tutorial which describes how to do this with 1 web cam at the following URL, and I have it working perfectly: [Video Capturing](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Video_Capturing).

Following that example, I use the following code on the form's `OnCreate` event, which stores the information of all the available video capture devices on the computer:

```
NumbAvailableCameras = 0;

DeviceList = TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->GetDevicesByMediaType(TMediaType::Video);
for (i = 0; i < DeviceList->Count; i++) {
    UniqueID = DeviceList->Items[i]->UniqueID;
    UniqueDescription = DeviceList->Items[i]->Description;
    UniqueName = DeviceList->Items[i]->Name;
    ComboBox1->Items->Add(DeviceList->Items[i]->Name);
    AvailableCameraIndices[NumbAvailableCameras] = i;
    AvailableCameraNames[NumbAvailableCameras] = DeviceList->Items[i]->Name;
    AvailableCameraDescriptions[NumbAvailableCameras] = UniqueDescription;
    AvailableCameraIdentifiers[NumbAvailableCameras] = UniqueID;
    CameraIndex[i] = i;
    NumbAvailableCameras++;
    }
```

Then, there is a button and its `OnClick` event allows the starting up of the capturing:

```
CAM1VideoCamera = dynamic_cast<TVideoCaptureDevice*>
        (TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->GetDevicesByName(ComboBox1->Selected->Text));
```

Now, I have 2 webcams whose names are identical, so the `GetDevicesByName()` routine doesn't work as it picks off the first camera it finds with the selected name.

As an alternative, I have tried the following code, but it returns `NULL` for the capture device:

```
CAM1VideoCamera = dynamic_cast<TVideoCaptureDevice*>
        (TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->Devices[CameraIndex[0]]);
```

Any ideas as to how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 webcams whose names are identical so the GetDevicesByName routine doesn't work as it picks off the **first** camera it finds with the selected name

Actually, it returns the **last** device with the selected name (bug?).

I find it odd that the method is named as a *plural* but it only returns a *single* device.

I have now reported these issues to Embarcadero:

[RSP-41707: TCaptureDeviceManager.GetDevicesByName() issues](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-41707)

> I have tried the following code but it returns NULL for the CaptureDevice

That is because you are using the wrong index.

You are retrieving a `TCaptureDeviceList` of just video devices, but then you are using indexes relative to that `TCaptureDeviceList` when accessing the main `TCaptureDeviceManager::Devices[]` list. So, if there are any audio devices present in the `Devices[]` list in front of the video devices then your `CameraIndex[]` indexes won't match up correctly, so you can end up passing a `TAudioCaptureDevice` object into `dynamic_cast`, which is why it would return `NULL`.

To do what you are attempting, you will have to forget about using `GetDevicesByMediaType()` and instead iterate the `Devices[]` list directly, eg:

```
NumbAvailableCameras = 0;

int DeviceCount = TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->Count;

for (int DeviceIndex = 0; DeviceIndex < DeviceCount; ++DeviceIndex) {
    TCaptureDevice *Device = TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->Devices[DeviceIndex];
    if (Device->MediaType != TMediaType::Video) continue;

    UniqueName = Device->Name;
    ComboBox1->Items->Add(UniqueName);

    AvailableCameraIndices[NumbAvailableCameras] = NumbAvailableCameras; // <-- or DeviceIndex?
    // Should this be a relative index to AvailableCameraIndices
    // or an absolute index to TCaptureDeviceManager?

    AvailableCameraNames[NumbAvailableCameras] = UniqueName;
    AvailableCameraDescriptions[NumbAvailableCameras] = Device->Description;
    AvailableCameraIdentifiers[NumbAvailableCameras] = Device->UniqueID;

    CameraIndex[NumbAvailableCameras] = DeviceIndex; // <--
    // definitely use absolute index here,
    // not a relative index!

    ++NumbAvailableCameras;
}
```

Now, accessing `TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->Devices[CameraIndex[...]]` should return only `TVideoCaptureDevice` objects, as expected.  In which case, since you know all indexes in  `CameraIndex[]` are only for video devices, you can (and should) use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`.

---

That being said, it appears that `AvailableCameraIndices[]` and `CameraIndex[]` *may* be doing the same job, so you might consider eliminating one of them.

Even better, consider changing `AvailableCameraIndices[]`/`CameraIndex[]` to store (a pointer to) the actual `TVideoCaptureDevice` object itself rather than storing an index to it, since the devices and indexes never change during `TCaptureDeviceManager`'s lifetime, eg:

```
NumbAvailableCameras = 0;

int DeviceCount = TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->Count;

for (int i = 0; i < DeviceCount; ++i) {
    TCaptureDevice *Device = TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->Devices[i];
    if (Device->MediaType != TMediaType::Video) continue;
    AvailableCameras[NumbAvailableCameras] = static_cast<TVideoCaptureDevice*>(Device);
    ++NumbAvailableCameras;
    ComboBox1->Items->Add(Device->Name);
}
```

In which case, you could just eliminate all of your separate `AvailableCamera...[]` arrays and just use `GetDevicesByMediaType()` by itself, eg:

```
AvailableCameras = TCaptureDeviceManager::Current->GetDevicesByMediaType(TMediaType::Video);

for (auto Device : AvailableCameras) {
    ComboBox1->Items->Add(Device->Name);
}
```

Comment: I ran into another issue.  I am setting up everything for use with the 2 web cams. When I go to start capturing, the first web cam starts ok.  The second cam will only start for a second (Green Light comes on the web cam) then immediately stops .  

In my next comment, I have included some code that I use for starting the process (Keep in mind the SampleBufferReady Routines are not included here but do work:

Comment: `code`
// Prepare the Camera Sample Threads
CAM1VideoCamera->OnSampleBufferReady = CAM1SampleBufferReady;
CAM1VideoCamera->Quality = TVideoCaptureQuality::PhotoQuality;
if(NumbCameras > 1) {
    CAM2VideoCamera->OnSampleBufferReady = CAM2SampleBufferReady;
    CAM2VideoCamera->Quality = TVideoCaptureQuality::PhotoQuality;
    }

// Now start capturing frames from the camera
CAM1VideoCamera->StartCapture();
if(NumbCameras > 1) CAM2VideoCamera->StartCapture();
'code'

Comment: If I set a breakpoint Before the StartCapture routines and step through it, cam1 works ok.  Cam2 only comes on for a brief second.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: @Drewski7280 that issue has nothing to do with your question in this post about just retrieving the capture devices. It warrants a separate post of its own. One question per post, please